# How do I send an HTML email with variables from a java servlet?

Tags: java, html, servlets

I currently have a server coded in Java (an amazon EC2 instance) which has many servlets to do various web services things. So far I have been sending the invitation emails using code like this:

```
public void sendInvitationEmail(String nameFrom, String emailTo, String withID)
        {

            SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest().withSource("invitation@myserver.com");

            List<String> toAddresses = new ArrayList<String>();
            toAddresses.add(emailTo);
            Destination dest = new Destination().withToAddresses(toAddresses);
            request.setDestination(dest);

            Content subjContent = new Content().withData("My Service Invitation Email");
            Message msg = new Message().withSubject(subjContent);

            String textVer = nameFrom +" has invited you to try My Service.";
            String htmlVer = "<p>"+nameFrom+" has invited you to try My Service.</p>";
            // Include a body in both text and HTML formats
            Content textContent = new Content().withData(textVer);
            Content htmlContent = new Content().withData(htmlVer);
            Body body = new Body().withHtml(htmlContent).withText(textContent);
            msg.setBody(body);

            request.setMessage(msg);

            try {           
                ses.sendEmail(request);
            }catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
                handleExceptions(ase);
            } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
                handleExceptions(ace);  
            }
        }
```

Whit this i have successfully sent emails which include the name of the person based on external variables generated by my code. My question is, How would i go about doing this with a more complex HTML email? I have generated an HTML file with a more complex layout and I still but it still needs to have these variables modified by my code. The file is an HTML so i THINK (not sure) that i could read it as a big string of text and just add it to the htmlVer String. But I was wondering if there is an easier way to read an HTML file and just change some variables and then simply add this to the content part of the Amazon SES.

Am I taking the wrong approach here?

Comment: Use an html template engine/framework like [thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/). Here's an email example: http://www.thymeleaf.org/springmail.html, with spring but you can do it with basic servlets obviously.

Comment: I found the engine framework called velocity. Or the one you just mentioned. but either way I have to create the HTML in those engines right? I cant create it by using tools like dreamweaver and such?

Comment: You could create it with dreamweaver, take the generated HTML, and add the attributes specific to thymeleaf or velocity afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Template Engine like Thymeleaf to process html and inject attributes.

It's as simple as this:

```
ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
resolver.setSuffix(".html");
TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(resolver);
final Context context = new Context(Locale.CANADA);
String name = "John Doe";
context.setVariable("name", name);

final String html = templateEngine.process("myhtml", context);
```

with a `myhtml.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-3.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>My first template with Thymeleaf</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="${name}">A Random Name</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

After the engine processes the HTML file, the variable `html` in the java code will contain the HTML above but will have replaced the contents of the `<p>` element with the value you pass in the context.

If you are using tools like DreamWeaver to make your html, it's not a problem. You can come in with a text editor and add the `th:text` (or other) attributes later. That's one of the strengths of Thymeleaf, you can do your templates and your java code separately and join them when you need to.

Comment: thank you very much, i was having trouble figuring the last part.

Comment: Hey again, I was wondering if you happened to know where should i locate my file. In my server structure because i keep getting the error that the html file could not be found. I thought it was in the WEB-INF folder but it cannot be found.

Comment: In this case, I believe it should be on the classpath. So, if you're in some IDE, make a folder a source folder and add it there. Otherwise, when you run it, add it to classpath with -cp.